# Как вывести Image объект на клиентской стороне?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, изображения

У меня есть функция, восстанавливающая изображение из Base64, и преображает его в объект Image

```
Image image = FromBase64(user.Avatar);
```

есть ли возможность использовать данную переменную в качестве изображения на клиенте? То есть в представлении .cshtml? 
**Не пытайтесь предлагать хранить эти картинки в системе, я хочу именно выгрузку из базы**

Comment: Динамически как-то так https://habr.com/ru/post/25606/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,@user.Avatar" alt="avatar"/>
```

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

Comment: Действительно. Мне это подходит, отмечу как ответ через 6 минут

Comment: base64 не самый лучший способ... зато... самый простой. Так же можно делать динамическую ссылку, которая по айди с базы будет картинку доставать... но это сложнее.

Comment: я это всего лишь для опыта делаю :)